# Adding custom login-config.xml errors saying mbean already installed

Tags: java, jboss, jaas

```
  Deployment "vfszip:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/fizio.ear/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.IllegalStateException: jboss:service=DynamicLoginConfig is already installed.
```

My war's META-INF contains the following jboss-service.xml:

```
<server>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.security.auth.login.DynamicLoginConfig"
        name="jboss:service=DynamicLoginConfig">
        <attribute name="AuthConfig">META-INF/login-config.xml</attribute>
        <depends optional-attribute-name="LoginConfigService">jboss.security:service=XMLLoginConfig</depends>
        <depends optional-attribute-name="SecurityManagerService">jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager</depends>
    </mbean>
</server>
```

I'm not using this mbean anywhere else as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

No one?

Am I missing something bigger than this? It feels like a database based username and password login should have been a solved issue for Java EE decades ago, but it still evades me.

Answer (score 0):

It's got to be used somewhere else.  Look through your {console|boot|server}.log during startup.  Somewhere there will be a message about deploying the earlier instance of jboss:service=DynamicLoginConfig.

Alternately, just change the name.  There's nothing magic about it AFAICT.

Comment: There's nothing in the console log about it and if I change the name to DynamicLoginConfig2, for example (I've tried many, many names) it still says the same thing - already installed. I've also exploded the ear and grepped for it with only one result.

Comment: That is odd.  Maybe an old or exploded version of your ear is sitting in your deploy directory?